# Passing by value or passing by reference

Tags: c++, parameters, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

```
void Subroutine1(int Parameter1)

void Subroutine2(const int &Parameter1)
```

In Subroutine1 we have to get a copy of the parameter while in Subroutine2 we don't have to make the copy, which may save some overhead.

In practice Subroutine1 seems being used more often than the other. Why is that the case?

Comment: If using ints, then you won't save any overhead because passing a pointer to an int takes as much time/memory as passing a copy of an int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In practice Subroutine1 seems being used more often than the other.
>   Why is that the case?

Because copying an int has is better over creating a reference (or pointer) and then accessing it.

More generally, all primitive types should be passed by value.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you are dealing with primitive types (such as `int`), passing by reference is actually *worse* performance-wise than passing by value. It also doesn't offer you anything.

Comment: Why "it is much more conventional to pass a pointer instead of a reference"?

Comment: @TerryLiYifeng: Because decades' worth of C code does it like that, so you 're much more likely to see people following that example. But there's nothing technically wrong with using a reference in that case.

Comment: @downvoter: Please help me improve this answer by leaving a comment.

Comment: @Jon Only old APIs and C programmers that never got used to C++ still do multiple return values that way.
Also, the multiple return value thing doesn't apply to a question about pass by value vs pass by const&.

Comment: @Dave: Fair enough. Deleted second paragraph to only leave the relevant bits in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

One passes an int, the other passes a reference. As others have said, creating and accessing a reference to an int isn't much difference than just copying the int.

(Edited as per correct comment)

Comment: It's not a matter of size. If a reference is implemented through a pointer, you have added the overhead of dereferencing that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Passing by reference is (almost always) implemented by passing a pointer. This means that, for simple types like `int`, the second version may be less efficient - passing a pointer has more or less the same cost as passing a simple object, and then the function needs to dereference that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

For primitive data types (like `int`, `double`, `char`) which are typically of smaller size, the 1st case is usually faster (accessibility) and cheaper compared to the 2nd one. Remember that references are implemented more or less similar to pointers.

On side note, if `Parameter1` is not going to be modified then, personally I will choose the 3rd alternative,

```
void Subroutine3(const int Parameter1);
```

Comment: What's the point of adding const here since the original data for Parameter1 wouldn't be altered anyway?

Comment: Indeed, `void Subroutine3(const int Parameter1);` and `void Subroutine3(int Parameter1);` declare the same function, so there is little reason to list your implementation details in the declarations (in headers).

Comment: @TerryLiYifeng, the purpose is to mention that `Parameter1` is *also* not altered inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Pass-by-reference to some extent implies that the callee can mutate whatever is referenced and have that mutation take effect in the caller. If that's the case you probably want to wrap the int an object and pass that into the function by reference. This provides more explicit code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, for int type, pass by value is faster than pass by reference. But for your own class and struct, pass by ref is faster.

The overhead difference between these two method for primitive types is actually very very small, you can ignore it in most cases.

In my opinion, const ref of primitive type parameter is useless for normal functions. And it makes the code a little bit obscurer, so do not use it.